# Linq: filter Ids from a list of class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list of Customers class

```
class Customers
{
int Id
string Name
}

List<Customers> CustomerList
```

Lets suppose this list contains 10 records.

I have to filter by the **Id** in the CustomerList from the following repo. I am trying to get the all the Ids from CustomerList and get associated records from CustomerRepostitory. CustomerRepository is a  class generated by edmx which reflects the Customer table in database. I cannot figure out a way to do that. This is what I have coded which is not working.

````
var status = this.CustomerRepository
                .Find(o => CustomerList.Id.Contains(o.Id))
                .Select(o => new
                {
                    o.Name,
                    o.CustomerCode,
                }) ```

How do I filter records by passing Id coming in CustomerList ?
````

Comment: Show us what this CustomerRepository is

Comment: I think you want `o=> CustomerList.Any(x => x.Id == o.Id)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is exactly in your repository, and what is its type, but you could try something like this:

```
int idYouLookingFor = 1;
var result = this.CustomerRepository
                .Where(c => c.Id == idYouLookingFor);
```